# With the demise of Dropbox for Linux, are there any alternative clients?

Tags: cloud

Dropbox are dropping support for Linux in November (with the exception of unencrypted Ext4).  They have an API, and on Android there are alternative clients (the best-known being dropsync) so it should be possible.  Is there an alternative client for Linux?

My requirements are bi-directional syncing without manual intervention as I use it to maintain some (fairly private) files on multiple machines (work/home/phone), so scripting a download of a link (which I've done before) won't work.  It doesn't look massively complicated to write one in Python, but has the feel of a project that could have hidden difficulties.

Note in case it's not clear: I'm not asking about alternative cloud storage/sync solutions, I'm asking about something to interact with an existing account and folder structure.

Comment: Are you asking for alternatives to Dropbox, which work with a Dropbox account ?

Comment: @XTian I was, yes - hence "client" and "not asking about alternative cloud storage".  Is there some other potential interpretation I haven't dismissed with these phrases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No alternative is needed, I simply:

- created an empty file,
- formatted it as ext4,
- mounted it as a loop device,
- moved dropbox home in it.

As an example:

1. Add to you `/etc/fstab` a line like this to mount, at boot, the dropbox filesystem.

   ```
   /home/user/.dropbox-store   /home/user/Dropbox   ext4    defaults,loop    0 0
   ```
2. Execute

   ```
   dropbox stop
   dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=1 seek=2097152 of=~/.dropbox-store
   /sbin/mkfs.ext4 -L DropboxHome ~/.dropbox-store 
   mv ~/Dropbox ~/Dropbox_
   mkdir ~/Dropbox
   # emulate boot mount to check fstab syntax 
   sudo mount -a
   sudo chown user.users ~/Dropbox
   rsync -av ~/Dropbox_/. ~/Dropbox/.
   dropbox start
   ```

It is a rough solution. It is just a roadmap that you have to adapt to your needs. E.g. the `fstab` solution is acceptable only on a single user laptop as mine.

Comment: Accepted as it's a nice clear write-up of how to do it, but I ended up reinstalling/upgrading for other reasons and went for full-disc encryption with an unencrypted ext4 filesystem as I did so, making the question moot

Comment: There is also a workaround that allows the use of Dropbox on non-ext4 filesystems. https://github.com/dark/dropbox-filesystem-fix as described in https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/how-to-use-dropbox-on-non-ext4.html?m=1

Comment: @LustreOne, please add a new answer to this question instead of a comment. That alternative is worth knowing, an answer will better advertise it.

Comment: How do you format a file as ext4 on linux? I know how to format a partition, but not a file.

Answer (score 4):

### Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS

Dropbox has brought back support for ZFS, XFS, Btrfs and eCryptFS on Linux. A Dropbox [client update](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Desktop-client-builds/Beta-Build-77-3-127/td-p/354660) brings back support for ZFS and XFS on 64-bit Linux systems, and eCryptFS and Btrfs on all Linux systems.

Links:

- [Dropbox Brings Back Support For ZFS, XFS, Btrfs And eCryptFS On Linux](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/dropbox-brings-back-support-for-zfs-xfs.html)
- [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral-dropbox) lightweight open source **alternative Dropbox client** for Linux

Answer (score 2):

There is also a workaround that allows the use of Dropbox on non-ext4 filesystems. https://github.com/dark/dropbox-filesystem-fix as described in https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/how-to-use-dropbox-on-non-ext4.html?m=1